# Java ee, JPA 2.1 retruning null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

frist of all sorry for my bad english. I am trying to display database (Postgres) rows from one table, and it allways returning null. I am doing project in Java EE using JPA hibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="mesPU">

        <class>pl.mes.model.Users</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Users entity

```
package pl.mes.model;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Users {
    private Integer userId;
    private String firstname;
    private String secondname;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = true)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "secondname", nullable = true)
    public String getSecondname() {
        return secondname;
    }

    public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
        this.secondname = secondname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Users users = (Users) o;

        if (userId != null ? !userId.equals(users.userId) : users.userId != null) return false;
        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(users.firstname) : users.firstname != null) return false;
        if (secondname != null ? !secondname.equals(users.secondname) : users.secondname != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(users.email) : users.email != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (secondname != null ? secondname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

When i use this

select u from Users u

in console output looks like that:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmBBW.png)

[DbSOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBIPk.png)
I would be grateful if someone can help me with this :)

Comment: You did not specify the annotation `@Table(name = "<name of table with users>")` for your entity (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733064/5223047) for further explanation). This means that there must exist a table named `Users`. If the table does exist, are you connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Firstly there is NO NEED to specify `@Table` (all of that is defaulted when not provided). Secondly debug your problem by looking in the LOG of the JPA provider and look at the SQL invoked.

Comment: I specified table and that didnt work. I addet screen of my dbsource. I think i am connecting to right database

Comment: Also why are you specifying Hibernate-specific connection info (hibernate.connection*) when you also provide JPA standard properties that are adequate to define the database in a portable way.

Comment: @BillyFrost It is true that there is no need to specify `@Table`. But if you don't, than there must a table exist that is named like the entity. Otherwise an (empty) table may be created by JPA.

Comment: @ltlBeBoy Wrong. ALL that `@Table` does is DEFINE the name, and if not provided then the default name is the same as the entity name. Table existence is a parallel concept, the table can be created by the JPA provider if you tell it to ...

Comment: @BillyFrost Look, if you have a table named `my_user` containing all the user data, and the name of the entity is `Users`, then (if specified) a new **and empty** table will be created by JPA. Select queries will be empty then...This is what was described in the question.

Comment: @ltlBeBoy You don't need to specify the Table annotation. Entity annotation is enough and it's not case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the URL `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test` for the property `javax.persistence.jdbc.url`. But when I look at the second screenshot, I can not see a database schema named `test`.

I guess, you are connecting to the wrong database. Maybe a second instance listening at a different port?

Please also remove the Hibernate specific properties that are already specified by JPA standard properties (as stated out in the comments by Billy Frost).

Comment: @SławekAdamiec Great! Please accept the answer by clicking on the check icon if this solved your problem.